# Where is the CorrelationID in MVC 6

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I get the correlationID of a request using MVC 6?

I want to use it when I log a message so that I can track a request through the system.

In previous versions I would have used the HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetCorrelationId method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.getcorrelationid%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the newest versions, `HttpContext` directly exposes a `TraceIdentifier` property you can use as a correlation identifier: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs#L72

```
public void MvcAction() {
    var identifier = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
}
```

In older versions, you might have to use the `IHttpRequestIdentifierFeature` feature to retrieve the request identifier:

```
public void MvcAction() {
    var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestIdentifierFeature>();
    var identifier = feature.TraceIdentifier;
}
```

Comment: Do you know why I cannot get the first option to work in beta8? 
When I look at the definition of HttpContext it is missing the TraceIdentifier property.

Comment: Because this property was added recently (6 days ago to be exact: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/440). Of course, it will be part of RC1, but in the meantime, you can find it in the nightly builds.